# Write SMS to folders (Inbox, Drafts, Sent Items) on Windows Mobile (Managed Code prefered)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am taking backup of message folders (Inbox, Drafts, Sent Items) from Windows Mobile to server. Now, I need to restore the messages to the corresponding folders after we wipe the Windows Moble.

How to write SMS to the corresponding folders (Inbox, Drafts, Sent Items)?

I found SimWriteMessage method of SIMMANAGER API. Its Native code. Does anyone have C# wrapper of this?

Answer (score 0):

I found CreateMessage function of MAPI ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc839874.aspx ) but don't know how to call from C#.

Comment: Thanks ctacke. But, I am developing product and cannot rely on third-party dependencies. Do you have code sample the performs this task without help of third-party solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly complex COM API set.  You'll have to either write an interop layer or use [a third-party solution](http://inthehand.co.uk/content/Mobile.aspx) that already did that work.